How to assign a value to the model property of a QML ListView instance in C++
While developing a dynamic layout, I had to implement ListView from qml file as QQuickItem instance in a C++ class, but there was a problem with assigning a value (inherited instance of QAbstractListModel) to the "model" property.
MyListViewModel lv("myListViewModel ", this);                         
lv.addAttribute({tr("Cycle"), 0, true, true});
lv.addAttribute({tr("Analogue"), 1, false, true});
lv.addAttribute({tr("Calculations"), 2, false, true}));

// Error no matching function for call to 'QVariant::QVariant(MyListViewModel &)'.

listViewItem->setProperty("model", QVariant(lv) ); 


What is the correct way to assign the model property to an instance of a class inherited from QAbstractListModel?
PS. Passing this model via setContextProperty in QML code works correctly, but I need a dynamic solution

Use a pointer. :-)

By using a pointer comes "error: use of deleted function ‘QVariant::QVariant(void*)’"
I take it you're just trying to guess the answer without knowing the correct solution.

maybe it doesn't let me understand. The first thing is that it seems that your model is a local variable so you must use a pointer or member class. Even so, QObjects must be passed as pointers to QML since they are not copyable. On the other hand to convert a QObject* to QVariant use QVariant::fromValue

And now you are absolutely right and everything is working. Thank you very much eyllanesc!

From this question and the one before, it seems you are doing C++/QML integration backward. I'd recommend you watching this : https://youtu.be/vzs5VPTf4QQ?t=23m20s , https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html#interacting-with-qml-objects-from-c and https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-bestpractices.html#separate-ui-from-business-logic
